# Move column headers in xamdatagrid to top of grid

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, hierarchical-data, xamdatagrid

I have a hierarchical data model:

```
public class AssetClassLevelViewModel
{    
     public string AssetClassName {get; set;}

     public ObservableCollection<AssetClassLevelViewModel> ChildAssetClasses {get; set;}

     public ObservableCollection<ProductHoldingsWithAllocationViewModel> ProductHoldings {get; set;}

}
```

The column headers seen in the image reflect the ProductHoldingsWithAllocationViewModel properties.

[image: A snapshot of the multi-level hierarchy and column headers]

I need to move the column headers on top of the grid, and do not want them repeating at each grouping level.

Is there a solution for this? In the xaml I've set the `HeaderPlacement` property to `OnTopOnly`

Thanks

Hasanain

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use the following style to make sure the header row is only at the top:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Ig:XamDataGrid}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Ig:XamDataGrid}}">
  <Setter Property="FieldLayoutSettings">
    <Setter.Value>
      <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings HeaderPlacement="OnTopOnly" HeaderPlacementInGroupBy="OnTopOnly"/>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I believe the "OnTopOnly" makes sure that the header row is only displayed at the very top of the grid, not in each group header.

Comment: What is the ExtendedXamDataGrid? Is that different from the XamDataGrid

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected that - it was a custom class that inherited the XamDataGrid and provided some extended functionality.  But it shouldn't make a difference for your purposes.

Comment: @Hasanain - did this work for you?  If so, please mark this as the answer.  If not perhaps you can provide more details.

Comment: This simply moved the headers to the top of the groups not to the top of the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late for an answer, but on your XamDataGrid in XAML, you just need to set the FilterUIType-Property to LabelIcons, and the ColumnHeaders will be at the top when the XamDataGrid is grouped. Just like here:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
   <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings FilterUIType="LabelIcons"/>
</igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics suggested the following workaround to me for hiding all child table headers:

Add a style for `DataRecordPresenter` to your resources:

```
<local:TestConverter2 x:Key="testconv2"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:DataRecordPresenter}">
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource testconv2}}"/>
</Style>
```

And add the following converter to your project:

```
public class TestConverter2 : IValueConverter
{
    private int count = 0;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataRecord dr = value as DataRecord;
        if (dr == null)
        {
            return double.NaN;
        }

        if (dr is HeaderRecord)
        {
            if (this.count < 1)
            {
                this.count++;
                return double.NaN;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return double.NaN;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```